# How to connect my backend with my frontend with angular2 and ionic2 using gridFs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, mongoose, ionic2

I have created a file in my database using `gridFs`. The file is as follows:

### storeAudio.js

```
   var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var fs = require('fs');
    var Grid = require('gridfs-stream');
    Grid.mongo=mongoose.mongo;


    //establish mongoDB connection
     mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
    var conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017/aHolyBoly');
    conn.once('open',function(){
       var gfs = Grid(conn.db);
     // var db = new mongo.Db('aHolyBoly', new mongo.Server("127.0.0.1", 27017));
    //var gfs = Grid(db, mongo);

    var writeStream = gfs.createWriteStream({
        filename:'song1.mp3'
    });
    fs.createReadStream('../list/hero.mp3').pipe(writeStream);
    writeStream.on('close',function(file){
        console.log(file.filename +'Written to db');
    });
    });
```

Now, I want to make an API using express and node so that I can connect my Backend with Frontend using `Ionic2` and `Angular2`.

So I saw this tutorial: 
[https://www.joshmorony.com/building-a-review-app-with-ionic-2-mongodb-node/](http://www.joshmorony.com/building-a-review-app-with-ionic-2-mongodb-node/)
Now in this tutorial, the HTTP verbs `GET`, `POST` etc are used to make the API calls and then it is used as a provider.So is this the way to continue with my project? And if this is the way then I have some questions which are below:

In the link mentioned above there is **server.js** file. In that file a code as `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/reviewking');` Why this is used again if already used in my file **storeAudio.js**?

Secondly, should the HTTP verbs be used in the similar fashion using `gridFs`?

Note: I am using first time everything (except `ionic2` and `angular2`).Please let me know if any more inputs should be provided. And Sorry for the mistakes if found in this post.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample function from one of my providers in an ionic 3 App which is making a call to my API:

```
getClients(){

let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Authorization', this.authService.token);

this.http.get('https://ptassist.herokuapp.com/api/auth/' + this.authService.user._id, {headers: headers})
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.clientlist = data;
    console.log(this.clientlist);
  }, (err) => {

    console.log(err);
  });





}
```

As for your other query about the mongoose connection, I'm not entirely sure, have you code your code on github etc?